# Area under a point

Tags: integration

My question relates to continuous functions. I understand that the integral, over an interval, is the area under the curve over that interval. However, if you are calculating, say, the probability of a single point in a continuous probability distribution function, why is the answer zero? Doesn't the width of that single point, while infinitely small, have to be greater than zero? If not, it would lead me to believe that the sum of the areas of every single point on the interval would be zero. I understand that it's mathematically not possible to calculate the area under a single point, but why do we say it's zero?

Comment: For there to be area, there must be width and height.  If the width is zero, it makes sense that the area would be zero.

Comment: What is the area of a rectangle of dimensions $L \times \epsilon$? What happens as $\epsilon \to 0$?

Comment: There's no such thing as "infinitely close" when it comes to real numbers. (Or complex numbers, for that matter. There are other, less well-known number systems which _do_ have infinitesimals, but even there you'd have trouble deciding exactly _which_ infinitesimal the area should be.)

Comment: You can introduce infinitesimals in this way, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a *very* common misconception about what Riemann integration does. The idea that many people have is that we're adding up the signed areas of infinitely-many vertical line segments, but this is patently not the case. We can always add up a finite multi-set (meaning repeats are allowed) of real numbers, and in "nice enough" cases, we can "add up" a countably-infinite multi-set of real numbers. However, if we want to add up an uncountable multiset, then we *have* to have only countably-many of them be non-$0$, and that countable collection has to be "nice enough." Indeed, adding up uncountably-many $0$s *does* get us $0$, but that isn't what we're doing.

If a function $f$ is "nice enough" to be integrable on a real interval $[a,b]$ (which can be made precise, but I don't want to digress more than necessary), then we can proceed as follows. For each integer $n\ge0$ define a real number $S_n$ by: $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}f\left(a+\frac{2k-1}{2}\cdot\frac{b-a}{2^n}\right)\cdot\frac{b-a}{2^n}$$ Visually, what we're doing is dividing $[a,b]$ up into $2^n$ sub-intervals of equal width--namely, $\frac{b-a}{2^n}$--and adding up the [signed areas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_area) of the rectangles with height given by the function values at the center points of the subintervals. (See the picture [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Methods) labeled "Middle" for the idea.) We then define $$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx:=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n.$$ At every stage, we were only adding up finitely-many signed areas of rectangles with positive width. At no point did we add an area of a vertical line segment.

Comment: A function just needs to be continuous on an interval to be Riemann integrable. That's not really that much to add.

Comment: Yes, it is *sufficient* for Riemann integrability that a function be continuous on an interval. It is not *necessary*, however.

Answer (score 0):

We say is zero, or more formally:

$$\int_a^af(x)dx=0$$

Intuitively, you can try to bound the area, if you take:

$$\int_a^{a+\delta}f(x)dx=0$$

For every "amount" of area, you will find a sufficiently small $\delta$ greater than zero that makes the integral smaller. In an image, if you start to make the interval smaller, then you can make the area as small as you want. That is, I think, th emost intuitive way to see this: Take any interval and draw the sum, then ask yourself if for every area you couldn't shrink the interval to get a lower area.

Also saying "it would lead me to believe that the sum of the areas of every single point on the interval would be zero" is wrong because we are adding an infinite number of this "zero" areas, and that yet again is not defined. That's the whole idea of the limit of the Riemann sum, you are adding infinite numbers, all of them infinitely small.

Of course we're dealing with well behaved functions, for example the Dirac's delta function (which is only properly defined in distribution theory) has a finite area on a single point from this intergral point of view.

Comment: What do you mean "it is not defined"? It is defined, precisely by the integral (with value zero) that you mentioned immediately after.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Ok

Answer (score -3):

To find the area under $1$ point IS possible,
Consider:
$y=\sqrt{-(x-a)^2}$ 
Where a is a real constant and $x$ and $y$ are real variables.
y only has 1 completely real value, that when $x=a$.
Thus the graph in Cartesian Plane would be of a single dot.
Trying to find the area will lead you to discover that it is 0, as you have nowhere to take boundaries from except from a to a, since the rest is not real.

Comment: While you do give an example of a graph consisting of a single real point, you do little to address the concerns expressed in the Question, i.e. why if the area under a point is zero, isn't the combined area under all points zero?