# How to use FTC2 on a discontinuous piecewise function?

Tags: calculus, integration, piecewise-continuity

> [image]

This exercise asks to evaluate the integral from 0 to pi. I worked it out by breaking the function into two integrals where the first had lower and upper limits of 0 and pi/2 respectively and adding it to the integral with lower and upper limits of pi/2 and pi respectively.

Now, since the integral is not continuous over its domain [0, pi/2], how can we use FTC2 on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still evaluate the integrals individually and then add them together. There is a jump discontinuity at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ due to the interval given in the piecewise, but this *point* will not impact the sum. That is because the *thickness* of a single point is intuitively $0$.

Consider the point $c$ (Note: c is finite):

$\int_c^{c} f(x) dx= F(c)-F(c)=0$ by the FTC.

Additionally, note that the function is integrable from that interval.

$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x) dx = [-\cos(x)]_0^{\pi/2} = 0-(-1) = 1$

Comment: Hi, yes, I can see why. However, does this discontinuity affect our ability to use FTC 2 as it requires continuity over [a, b]?

Comment: It does not because the sum of one point is, intuitively, $0$. In other words, a point has no thickness/width to sum.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. So I would be correct in saying that in a case like this, there is some flexibility to the theorem?

Comment: @Oofy2000 No because $\sin(x)$ is integrable/well defined/continuous from $0 \le x \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Ok. Still seems to me that it doesn't answer the question - you _say_ that that single point does not affect the "sum"; in fact a single point does not affect an integral, but **why not???*

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I believe the OP is in first-year calculus so I have stuck with an intuitive argument.

Comment: I am indeed in first year calculus. So I am still wrapping my head around a few things. I'd be happy to have a read of a very detailed response to see if I can understand

Comment: @Oofy2000 Added one. Here is a rigorous explanation, if interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511197/area-under-a-point

Comment: @Oofy2000 The other answer leaves a few details out but does give an actual proof

Answer (score 1):

First prove this, from the definition of the integral:

> > **Prop.** Suppose $p\in[a,b]$, and $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ satisfies $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]\setminus\{p\}$. Then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^bf=0$.

Hence, even though $f(x)-\sin(x)$ does not quite vanish at *every* point, it follows that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}(f(x)-\sin(x))\,dx=0,$$hence $$\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)\,dx.$$

(Technicality: Since $\sin(x)$ and $f(x)-\sin(x)$ are both integrable on $[0,\pi/2]$, so is $f$.